# neko and windows compiled targets not showing up

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, neko

I compile an openfl project from flashdevelop to neko.
It says "Build successful" but I don´t get a neko window or anything. 
I see the .exe in my task manager but where is it?
Same happens for windows target.

flash, html, android, they all work.

Comment: You Build project (F8) or Test project (F5)?
I build you should find build at bin/windows folder